# Having two Facebook request paths in same controller iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am having a controller where I need issue multiple facebook requests. How do I tell the request appart in this delegate method?

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result { ... }
```

I need to do one thing for one request and another thing for the other request.

Answer (score 0):

How about write individual class request & results from delegates , i used to try this when in Single View i need to take Friends List, Checkins Data , User Info.

i ll create three separate delegate results & get results back .

However making multiple requests will work but it will create bad performances when any one of the requests failed or goes wrong.

Hope it helps

Updated :

```
userInfo *uInfo = [UserInfo alloc]init];
[uinfo getuserDetails];
[uInfo release];
```

create a protocol to return results of user info back to view class like
In UsuerInfo class

```
-(void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {

[delegate finfinishedGettingUserInfoDetails:result] // convert to array

 }
```

IN your view class get back the results as

```
 -(void)finishedGettingUserInfoDetails : (NSMutableArray *)userArr {

    yourInstanceArray = [userArr copy];
```

}

do this for all multiple requests.

Comment: Karthikeyan:Could you provide some examples?